# docker compose cannot start. Fails with "bufio.scanner token too long"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was using an editor in a docker container started by docker-compose, and copied too much text into it causing the container to hang.

I have manually stop the docker-compose services with docker.

But I realize I wasn't able to run docker-compose commands like up or down anymore and it fails with "bufio.scanner token too long" error.

I tried uninstalling docker-compose and docker but to no avail. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

turns out that i still have to remove that long piece of text from a file that i shared to the container's volume to get it working again